# How can foreach() in the parallel R package be handled a repeat loop with breaks?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have written a routine that takes considerable time without parallelization.

The issue is that I am unsure what to iterate over, since I have a repeat loop with breaks.

The loop consists of the following code snippet (for loop not shown):

```
repeat{
    if(R < p){
        HAC.sim(K = K, N = ceiling(Nstar), Hstar = Hstar, probs = probs, perms = perms, equal.freq = FALSE, subset.haps = NULL)
} else{
    break
  }
}
```

I would like to use foreach() with the parallel backend; however I am not certain what is needed for

```
foreach(i = 1:???){
    some code
}
```

since, I do not know ahead of time when the repeat loop will stop.

Comment: What is r and p? What Hac.sim does? How do you store the results you compute in parallel?

Comment: HAC.sim is a user-defined function. I left it out for brevity's sake. R is a variable in HAC.sim and p is a value (usually 0.9 or 0.95) that is basically a stopping criterion that tells the loop when to break.

Comment: HAC.sim outputs some performance measures... I have not yet defined a storage vector for parallel computation. I would just like to know the general structure that I need for foreach() when using a repeat loop.

Comment: Could you replace this function by a simpler one and make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: So basically, ``R`` is an output of ``HAC.sim`` and you want to stop calling it when R is large enough? What is the use of the foreach then, just to parallelize?

Comment: Yes I just need foreach() because my routine is slow... up to 3 hours or more depending on input parameters to the function HAC.sim. There is a chance that parallelization could cause parallel slowdown, but it's good to try it anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on only the number of cores you have. 
Then you can detect with memory-mapping when one core has found the solution and then stop the others.

```
library(bigstatsr)
library(foreach)

ncores <- nb_cores()  # or parallel::detectCores() - 1
fbm <- FBM(1, 1, init = 0)   # shared memory
p <- 0.9999
HAC.sim <- function() runif(1)

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

res <- foreach(i = 1:ncores, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  repeat {
    if (fbm[1] != 0) return(NULL)
    R <- HAC.sim()
    if (R >= p) {
      fbm[1] <- 1   # tell the others to stop
      return(R)
    } 
  }
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)

res
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks!